# 'play', 'practice' and/or 'do' martial art?

Tags: word-choice

Is it correct to say:

> I am practicing martial art in the park?

Can we also say 'play' or 'do' martial art?

Comment: It should be "martial arts", unless you are talking about one specific type of martial art, in which case, the actual name would work aswell as the plural. If you wanna stay unspecific, "a martial art" would also work, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 2):

The idiomatic verb to use for performing martial arts is **practice**: I am *practicing* martial arts in the park.  This is the verb I would use to mean "training in the martial art".  [You do occasionally see people use "to *do* karate"](http://www.extremetech.com/extreme/193966-oh-great-humans-taught-a-robot-how-to-do-karate), as *do* is about the most generic verb one can use for activities.

For example, [from Black Belt Magazine](http://www.blackbeltmag.com/category/daily/traditional-martial-arts-training/?topicid=2552):

> Morihei Uyeshiba practiced tenjin shinyo-ryu jujutsu...

[From the Martial Arts Stack Exchange](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/2108/how-can-one-practice-well-alone):

> How can one practice well alone?

And [from a karate instructor](http://www.karatebyjesse.com/why-you-should-avoid-telling-people-you-practice-karate/):

> Why You Should Avoid Telling People You Practice Karate

In general, we *play* sports that use a ball or similar equipment (I *play* football in the park; I *play* badminton after work) and we *do* gerunds or things that don't easily fall into another category: I *do* yoga in the park; I *do* my stretching in the park.

(I used to train in Shotokan karate, many years ago.)

Answer (score 0):

Martial arts are codified systems and traditions of combat practices ([the source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martial_arts)).

What you are doing in the park may be described as *practicing/exercising/mastering/perfecting your martial-arts skill*.

Also, you can *demonstrate, perform, show,* or *apply/use* your martial-arts skill according to the actual situation.

For more collocations with the noun skill [see here](http://oxforddictionary.so8848.com/search?word=skill) .

Regarding the second question, I don't see how martial arts, being systems and traditions, can be *played or done*.